# Regex - Exclude a match if it is preceeded by a specific character

Tags: regex

I am attempting to parse a string and return the stuff between the `#`, but only if the `#` is not preceded by a `\`.

For example, I was messing around with the following test string on regexr.com:

> This is a #date# test.

Using `#.*#` I'm able to retrieve the test I want. However, give this string:

> This is a \#date# test.

I don't want it to return as the backslash is in front of the `#`. Thus far, I've come up with:

```
[^\\](#.*.#)
```

However, when a backslash isn't present in the test string, it ends up grabbing whichever character is in front of the #. Is there any way to grab just the "#date#" part from the test string but only if it is not preceded by a blackslash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex lookbehind for your case.

You can use this regex:

```
(?<!\\)#(.*?)#
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/yT7oF3/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
\\#|#(.*?)#
```

**Note:** You can access your match result from capturing group `#1`

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xO5yB9/1)

Comment: universal! truly taking advantage of the RegEx engine